# Distractor objects are not added when creating a dataset using linemod format of bop_challenge using BlenderProc

Tags: python

#### Describe the issue

I am adding the code for adding TLESS/YCBV distractors but they are not added. Why is this issue caused and how can I fix it?

```
import blenderproc as bproc
import argparse
import os
import numpy as np

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('bop_parent_path', default='models_obj', help="Path to the bop datasets parent directory")
parser.add_argument('cc_textures_path', default="/home/mona/BlenderProc/examples/datasets/bop_challenge/texture_dir", help="Path to downloaded cc textures")
parser.add_argument('output_dir', default='/home/mona/BlenderProc/examples/datasets/bop_challenge/output_data', help="Path to where the final files will be saved ")
parser.add_argument('--num_scenes', type=int, default=200, help="How many scenes with 25 images each to generate")
args = parser.parse_args()

bproc.init()

SIZE=10

# load bop objects into the scene
# target_bop_objs = bproc.loader.load_bop_objs(bop_dataset_path = os.path.join(args.bop_parent_path, 'lm'), mm2m=True,
#                                             num_of_objs_to_sample=SIZE, obj_ids=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
target_bop_objs = bproc.loader.load_bop_objs(bop_dataset_path = os.path.join(args.bop_parent_path, 'lm'), mm2m=True,
                                            num_of_objs_to_sample=1, obj_ids=[1])
# load distractor bop objects
tless_dist_bop_objs = bproc.loader.load_bop_objs(bop_dataset_path = os.path.join(args.bop_parent_path, 'tless'), model_type = 'cad', mm2m = True)
# print("tless_dist_bop_objs: ", tless_dist_bop_objs)
# print("len(tless_dist_bop_objs): ", len(tless_dist_bop_objs))
ycbv_dist_bop_objs = bproc.loader.load_bop_objs(bop_dataset_path = os.path.join(args.bop_parent_path, 'ycbv'), mm2m = True)
# print('len(ycbv_dist_bop_objs): ', len(ycbv_dist_bop_objs))
# tyol_dist_bop_objs = bproc.loader.load_bop_objs(bop_dataset_path = os.path.join(args.bop_parent_path, 'tyol'), mm2m = True)

# load BOP datset intrinsics
bproc.loader.load_bop_intrinsics(bop_dataset_path = os.path.join(args.bop_parent_path, 'lm'))

# set shading and hide objects
#for obj in (target_bop_objs):# + tless_dist_bop_objs + ycbv_dist_bop_objs + tyol_dist_bop_objs):
# for obj in (target_bop_objs + tless_dist_bop_objs): # adding tless objects as distractors
for obj in (target_bop_objs + ycbv_dist_bop_objs): # adding tless objects as distractors
    obj.set_shading_mode('auto')
    obj.hide(True)
    
# create room
room_planes = [bproc.object.create_primitive('PLANE', scale=[10, 10, 1]),
               bproc.object.create_primitive('PLANE', scale=[10, 10, 1], location=[0, -10, 10], rotation=[-1.570796, 0, 0]),
               bproc.object.create_primitive('PLANE', scale=[10, 10, 1], location=[0, 10, 10], rotation=[1.570796, 0, 0]),
               bproc.object.create_primitive('PLANE', scale=[10, 10, 1], location=[10, 0, 10], rotation=[0, -1.570796, 0]),
               bproc.object.create_primitive('PLANE', scale=[10, 10, 1], location=[-10, 0, 10], rotation=[0, 1.570796, 0])]


# sample light color and strenght from ceiling
light_plane = bproc.object.create_primitive('PLANE', scale=[12, 12, 1], location=[0, 0, 14])
light_plane.set_name('light_plane')
light_plane_material = bproc.material.create('light_material')

# sample point light on shell
light_point = bproc.types.Light()
light_point.set_energy(500)

# load cc_textures
cc_textures = bproc.loader.load_ccmaterials(args.cc_textures_path)

# Define a function that samples 6-DoF poses
def sample_pose_func(obj: bproc.types.MeshObject):
    min = np.random.uniform([-0.3, -0.3, 0.0], [-0.2, -0.2, 0.0])
    max = np.random.uniform([0.2, 0.2, 0.4], [0.3, 0.3, 0.6])
    obj.set_location(np.random.uniform(min, max))
    obj.set_rotation_euler(bproc.sampler.uniformSO3())
    
# activate depth rendering without antialiasing and set amount of samples for color rendering
bproc.renderer.enable_depth_output(activate_antialiasing=False)
bproc.renderer.set_max_amount_of_samples(100)

for i in range(args.num_scenes):

    # Sample bop objects for a scene
    #sampled_target_bop_objs = list(np.random.choice(target_bop_objs, size=1, replace=False))
    #sampled_distractor_bop_objs = list(np.random.choice(tless_dist_bop_objs, size=5, replace=False))
    sampled_distractor_bop_objs = list(np.random.choice(ycbv_dist_bop_objs, size=10, replace=False))

    # Randomize materials and set physics
    #for obj in (sampled_target_bop_objs):# + sampled_distractor_bop_objs):        
    for obj in (sampled_target_bop_objs + sampled_distractor_bop_objs):   # using YCBV as distractor objects
        mat = obj.get_materials()[0]
        if obj.get_cp("bop_dataset_name") in ['itodd', 'tless']:
            grey_col = np.random.uniform(0.1, 0.9)   
            mat.set_principled_shader_value("Base Color", [grey_col, grey_col, grey_col, 1])        
        mat.set_principled_shader_value("Roughness", np.random.uniform(0, 1.0))
        mat.set_principled_shader_value("Specular", np.random.uniform(0, 1.0))
        obj.hide(False)
    
    # Sample two light sources
    light_plane_material.make_emissive(emission_strength=np.random.uniform(3,6), 
                                    emission_color=np.random.uniform([0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]))  
    light_plane.replace_materials(light_plane_material)
    light_point.set_color(np.random.uniform([0.0,0.0,0.0],[1,1,1]))
    location = bproc.sampler.shell(center = [0, 0, 0], radius_min = 1, radius_max = 1.5,
                            elevation_min = 5, elevation_max = 89)
    light_point.set_location(location)

    # sample CC Texture and assign to room planes
    random_cc_texture = np.random.choice(cc_textures)
    for plane in room_planes:
        plane.replace_materials(random_cc_texture)
        

    # Sample object poses and check collisions 

    
    
    bproc.object.sample_poses(objects_to_sample = sampled_target_bop_objs + sampled_distractor_bop_objs,  # using YCBV as distractor objc es
                            sample_pose_func = sample_pose_func, 
                             max_tries = 1000)
            
    # Define a function that samples the initial pose of a given object above the ground
    def sample_initial_pose(obj: bproc.types.MeshObject):
        obj.set_location(bproc.sampler.upper_region(objects_to_sample_on=room_planes[0:1],
                                                    min_height=1, max_height=4, face_sample_range=[0.4, 0.6]))
        obj.set_rotation_euler(np.random.uniform([0, 0, 0], [0, 0, np.pi * 2]))

    # Sample objects on the given surface
    
    placed_objects = bproc.object.sample_poses_on_surface(objects_to_sample=sampled_target_bop_objs + sampled_distractor_bop_objs, # using TLESS as distractor objects
                                                           surface=room_planes[0],
                                                           sample_pose_func=sample_initial_pose,
                                                           min_distance=0.01,
                                                           max_distance=0.1,
                                                           max_tries=1000,
                                                           )

    # BVH tree used for camera obstacle checks

    
    bop_bvh_tree = bproc.object.create_bvh_tree_multi_objects(sampled_target_bop_objs + sampled_distractor_bop_objs) # using YCBV as distractor objects


    cam_poses = 0
    while cam_poses < 25:
        # Sample location
        location = bproc.sampler.shell(center = [0, 0, 0],
                                radius_min = 3,
                                radius_max = 3.1,
                                elevation_min = 80,
                                elevation_max = 88)
                                # elevation_min = 5,
                                # elevation_max = 89)
        # Determine point of interest in scene as the object closest to the mean of a subset of objects
        poi = bproc.object.compute_poi(np.random.choice(sampled_target_bop_objs + sampled_distractor_bop_objs, size=SIZE, replace=False))
        #poi = bproc.object.compute_poi(np.random.choice(sampled_target_bop_objs, size=SIZE, replace=False))
        # Compute rotation based on vector going from location towards poi
        rotation_matrix = bproc.camera.rotation_from_forward_vec(poi - location, inplane_rot=np.random.uniform(-1.396, 1.396))

        # Add homog cam pose based on location an rotation
        cam2world_matrix = bproc.math.build_transformation_mat(location, rotation_matrix)
        
        # Check that obstacles are at least 0.3 meter away from the camera and make sure the view interesting enough
        if bproc.camera.perform_obstacle_in_view_check(cam2world_matrix, {"min": 0.1}, bop_bvh_tree):
            # Persist camera pose
            bproc.camera.add_camera_pose(cam2world_matrix, frame=cam_poses)
            cam_poses += 1

    # render the whole pipeline
    data = bproc.renderer.render()
    nocs_data = bproc.renderer.render_nocs()
    bproc.writer.write_hdf5("output_nocs", nocs_data, append_to_existing_output=True)

    # Write data in bop format
    bproc.writer.write_bop(os.path.join(args.output_dir, 'bop_data'),
                           target_objects = sampled_target_bop_objs,
                           dataset = 'lm',
                           depth_scale = 1.0,
                           depths = data["depth"],
                           colors = data["colors"], 
                           color_file_format = "JPEG",
                           ignore_dist_thres = 10)
    
    for obj in (sampled_target_bop_objs):# + sampled_distractor_bop_objs):      
    for obj in (sampled_target_bop_objs + sampled_distractor_bop_objs): # using YCBV as distractor objects
        obj.hide(True)
```

#### Expected behavior

to add random ycbv objects as distracted to the dataset with my object of interest

#### BlenderProc version

commit f34774b9d835b6dada02d7ab79ab33c542f87cf3

Comment: Hello. This looks like this question does not directly concern blender or blender's API but third party addons or modules, so it is considered off-topic on this site. Also, it is very hard to pinpoint exactly where your error lies since you just dumped your entire script without going into details about what work or doesn't work. You might have better luck by going directly to the github issues of relevant modules / addons. Cheers

Comment: @Gorgious so actually objects are added but they are much smaller than my object so they are barely distracting. My object diameter is 1.5 m. Is there set of bigger objects I could use for distraction than YCB-V dataset?

Comment: Hello ! You seem to assume I have knowledge about what you are talking about, but I don't and I don't think anyone here does, so again you may want to either contact the responsible parties directly or add a little more background to your question. What's YCB-V for starters ? Cheers

Comment: https://paperswithcode.com/dataset/ycb-video
I ended up using basic shapes for now and scaled them up. Kinda works to create occlusion using these bigger distractors.